# Is it possible to fallback to AuthorizedWhenInUse when a user doesn't allow AuthorizedAlways in iOS?

Tags: ios, permissions, gps, core-location

My app uses user location in the background, but sometimes, users don't allow the app to always collect GPS data. The app can handle foreground only locations, and I'd like to set that as a fallback.

Is there a graceful way, once an iOS user has declined my AuthorizedAlways request, to re-prompt the user to give AuthorizedWhenInUse permission ?

Comment: Give the user two options up front. Explain the benefits of AuthorizedAlways and the drawbacks. Personally If I am asked for Always I usually trash the app unless I am given a good reason of why this will benefit me. I actually value my privacy and better life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't force it, but you can:

1) know that user is declined permission
2) and show an alert asking: "Please, go to settings and enable it".
3) go to ios settings (`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];`)

Something like this:

```
- (void)checkLocation
{
    CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways){
        NSLog(@"ok");
    } else if(status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied ||
              status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse){
        [self showRequestLocationMessage];
    } else if(status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined){
        //request auth
    }

}

- (void)showRequestLocationMessage
{
    UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Settings"
                                                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * alertAction){
                                                       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
                                                   }];

    NSString *title = @"Service Enable";
    NSString *text = @"Please enable your location.. bla bla bla";

    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                                          alertControllerWithTitle:title
                                          message:text
                                          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){
                                                             [alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                         }];

    [alertController addAction:cancelAction];
    [alertController addAction:action];

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```